# How to ensure that a record cannot reference one of its children as its parent

Tags: postgresql, tree, constraints

I have a tree of groups represented by two tables.

The first one just contains the groups data:

```
CREATE TABLE "group" (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    label VARCHAR
);
```

The second one just handles the relations between groups to model the tree:

```
CREATE TABLE tree (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id uuid REFERENCES tree(id),
    group_id uuid UNIQUE REFERENCES "group"(id)
);
```

**I would like to ensure that a record in `tree` cannot reference one of its children in its `parent_id` field.**

---

From what I undersand, I cannot use [`CHECK`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) because it can use the data from only the current record, and I cannot use [`EXCLUDE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) because I do not have an operator that could do such a comparison.

I am already able to list ancestors and descendants of a given group using recursive CTEs but I cannot find a way to use it in a constraint.
[Here is a fiddle which could potentially clarify what I mean (if needed).](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=bc95ffee753df85f11fee50fdeef546a)

I am aware that it is possible with a trigger, but I would prefer to avoid it for performance concerns.
I am also aware that using [`ltree`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ltree.html) could make it easier, but I am not allowed to refactor the whole thing.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a constraint.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe So you would use a trigger? or maybe something else to address this issue?

Comment: Yes, I would use a trigger. But be aware that there can be race conditions unless you use `SERIALIZABLE` isolation, so this is only a good option with low concurrency.